# Alternative for Uninstall.ps1 as it is not run for nuget 3.x

Tags: powershell, nuget, uninstallation, nuget-package

In NuGet 3.x onwards in projects which use project.json the Install.ps1 and Uninstall.ps1 files are not run. Is there an alternate method by which I can run a powershell script when my package is uninstalled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, however its not correct when you say it as NuGet 3.x onwards, NuGet 3.0+ clients working on projects using project.json way of managing dependencies will not run install/uninstall scripts but if the project is using the packages.config then these scripts are run.

One alternative you can look at is have a VS extension that listens for reference add and executes some action using VS extensibility.

Comment: I had missed the project.json detail. Thanks for pointing it out :)