# Nuget update calls uninstall.ps1 and then install.ps1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

When using Nuget to update an already installed package, it calls "uninstall.ps1" and then "install.ps1". For the custom project I am working on, I need to know in "uninstall.ps1" what the reason for the call to uninstall is. Is it because the package is being updated or removed? Based on the reason I would want to process different logic.

It seems that it might be possible to know the difference because the console output for an update says:

> Resolved actions to **install** package '[Id].[Version]' Executing script file **'uninstall.ps1'**...

but for an uninstall it says:

> Resolved actions to **uninstall** package '[Id].[Version]' Executing script file **'uninstall.ps1'**...

Notice that the script called is the same but the Nuget action is different. Is the Nuget action (install vs uninstall) retrievable from some variable, property, or even a temporary file? This behavior seems to be the same no matter if using VS2012, VS2013, or VS2015.

Comment: There is no update.ps1 script.  So in order to update the package, it ensures that any side-effects of the *old* install script are undone by running uninstall.ps1.  And runs install.ps1 next.  Otherwise the same things that happen when you update by removing the package first and adding it again next.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could share the detailed steps here about how you really install and update the package in your side. What is your VS2015 and NuGet version?

[Alternative for Uninstall.ps1 as it is not run for nuget 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832174/alternative-for-uninstall-ps1-as-it-is-not-run-for-nuget-3-x)

I test a simple sample using the Package manager console in the latest VS2015 with NuGet 3.5, I install an old package, and then I install the new one or update it, it would remove the old version even if I didn't find the same messages as yours.

[image]